# ajax reporting success but nothing changing on the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

First, thanks for you reading. Here is my code

scripts/complete_backorder.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['order_id'])) {
    exit();
} else {

    $db = new PDO("CONNECTION INFO");

    $order = $db->prepare("UPDATE `scs_order` SET `order_complete`= 1 WHERE `order_id` = :var");

    $order->bindValue( ':var',$_GET['order_id'] );

 if ( $order->execute() ) {
        echo "DONE";
    };
};

?>
```

js/tabs.js

```
/*
[#]===============================================================================[#]
MODAL: "complete_backorder_Modal"
USAGE: modal to confirm whether or not user want to complete a backorder.
[#]===============================================================================[#]
*/

$(function(){

    $(" .remove_record ").click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();

        var rows = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("tr:last").index() + 1;
        var order = $(this).attr("href");

        var dataString = 'order_id='+order;

        $( '#complete_backorder_Modal' ).modal({
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });

        $( '#complete_backorder_Modal #modal-yes' ).click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../scripts/complete_backorder.php",
                data: dataString,
                success:  function(data){
                alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
                }
            });
        });


    });

});
```

so i know the php code is working as ive tested it over and over manually. but when i click on the ".remove_record" button the modal shows and i click the yes button in the modal the alert boxes shows up to say it was successful but when i look at the database nothing has changed.

any ideas?

Comment: Try to debug your query execution. Add `echo $order->errorCode();` and `print_r($order->errorInfo());` after `$order->execute()` line.

Comment: You have specified `POST` as type in your ajax call yet you use `GET` in your php code. Change your type to `GET`, remove `data` and change `url` to `"../scripts/complete_backorder.php/?" + dataString`

Comment: this is what im getting back
00000
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
Yet the database has updated, ive done this with the php file and not with the ajax way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is never running becuase there are no $_GET variables, your are using $_POST But even if you did you are not passing through order_id correctly. Change:

```
var postData = {'order_id ' : order}; // instead of  var dataString = 'order_id='+order;
```

And

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../scripts/complete_backorder.php",
        data: postData, // instead of dataString
        success:  function(data){
            alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
        }
 });
```

In the PHP change:

```
if(!isset($_POST['order_id'])) { // Insetad of $_GET
```

And

```
$order->bindValue( ':var',$_POST['order_id'] );
```

Comment: made all of the changes but its still not working, but at least the alert box isn't firing to say its been successful.

Comment: @Ajking11 Do you know about viewing the console? In Google Chrome press f12 and click the console tab. Click on the button in your page and post what is reported in the console

Comment: @Ajking11 ok so there arent any javascript errors, click on the Network tab and then click your button. You should see a request to your backorder script. Click on it and then click the Response tab and post what it shows

Comment: Cheers all after prodding a poking it i managed to get it working